# Not able to display image from database on webpage

Tags: php, css, database

I am not able to display my full image on my webpage from database
my codemy image is goint to database

[image: my database image]

```
$con=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");

        if(!$con)
       {
           die('not connected');
       }
            $result=  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT addplace, stayamount, foodamount, airlinesamount, noofdays,noofnights, 
    SUM(stayamount + foodamount + airlinesamount) AS totalamount,choose
FROM adddetails GROUP BY packageid");



?>
<div class="container">
<CENTER><h2>view packages</h2>
</CENTER>  
<table class="table table-bordered">

  <th>place</th>
  <th>stay cost</th>
  <th>food cost</th>
  <th>flight cost</th>
  <th>no of days</th>
  <th>no of nights</th>
  <th>total amount</th>
  <th>image</th>


        <?php

             while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))

             {
                 ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['addplace']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stayamount']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['foodamount'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['airlinesamount'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['noofdays'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['noofnights'] ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['totalamount'] ;?></td>
              <td><?php echo '<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['choose'] ).'>'; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
             }
             ?>
             </table>
            </div>
  </div>
```

[image: my web page]

please rewrite my code and i want my image of 150*150 size to be fitted on my web page in my table

Comment: $row['choose'] is binary formated or base64 formated in DB ? 
If u already has data formated as base64 u dont need to extra base64_encode in php.

Comment: <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['choose'] ).'">'; ?></td> . I added quotations for the src

Comment: Could you show us what is displayed when you type `echo $row['choose'];` without the encoding and the <img part>

Comment: Its just showing the name of that pic...i want the image to be displayed @Ann-SophieAngermüller

Comment: Try what's in @Cr1xus comment! You're missing quotations on your code..

Comment: Excuse me, did I really read **PLEASE REWRITE MY CODE**?
Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remember we are not a free coding service ;)

Comment: So what exactly do you save in the Database the whole image as blob or only the name of the image or what exactly?

Comment: the name of the image @Ann-SophieAngermüller

Comment: @gudisa Well, where is the image saved on your webserver and why do you even save the name as a blob then? oO

Answer (score 1):

try using this.

```
<td><img src='".$row['choose']."'/></td>";
```

Comment: his row is called choose and is a blob. So he saved the image directly in the db

Comment: I have changes it. for that naming reason doesn't make any sense to downvote,

Comment: It is not because of the naming, iit is because you assume the image is saved on his webserver, but he saved the image directly encoded in his database. so there is no folder where the image might be

Comment: it dint work @Ann-SophieAngermüller..its showing as my previous code

Comment: @this.Believer look at the Comments at top: gudisa only saves the name so basically you are right. i'm sorry for my temporarly downvote